# Display data like Table of Contents list from database (PHP SQL)

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I got a problem when I want to display data from database..

t_group :

[image]

t_type :

[image]

t_detail :

[image]

I try want to display data list table like here :

[image]

But my code here :

```
SELECT t_detail.id_detail, t_detail.name_detail, t_detail.qty,
       t_type.name_type,
       t_group.name_group
FROM t_detail, t_type, t_group
WHERE t_detail.id_type = t_type.id_type
AND t_detail.id_group = t_group.id_group
```

Here the result :

[image]

I want to display it like this :

[image]

Anyone please guide me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can give columns specific headings by referencing them like this: `t_detail.id_detail AS 'code'` i.e. `SELECT t_detail.id_detail AS 'code', t_detail.name_detail as 'list detail'` to help you start off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `UNION` AND `SUM` functions to get the expected result.

```
SELECT name_detail,id_detail as name , qty  FROM t_detail

UNION 

SELECT t_group.name_group,t_group.id_group as name, (SELECT sum(t_detail.qty)  FROM t_detail WHERE t_detail.id_group=t_group.id_group GROUP BY t_detail.id_group) AS qty FROM t_group

UNION 

SELECT name_type , id_type as name, (select sum(t_detail.qty)  from t_detail where t_detail.id_type = t_type.id_type
GROUP BY t_detail.id_type) as qty FROM t_type ORDER BY `name`  ASC
```

It's better to build the query step by step ,so that you will be able to get the answer much quicker and easily.

I hope this will help you.